# How to combine two text hyper links

Tags: php, javascript, html

Let say we've the following hyper link code

```
<a id="cont" href="www.first_site.com">Something</a>
```

and i'd like to combine it with pop up using the following java code

```
<script language="javascript">
var popupWindow = null;
function centeredPopup(url,winName,w,h,scroll){
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
settings =
'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
popupWindow = window.open(url,winName,settings)
}
</script>

<a href="www.second_site.com" onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','500','300','yes');return false">Anything</a>
```

Is there any idea i can combine both so that when i click on `Something` at 1st hyper link , it open up the pop up of `www.second_site.com` and moves to `www.first_site.com`

any help ~ thanks

Comment: You forgot `http://` in your URLs. A link starting with anything but a protocol or `//` is relative to the current url/path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand you…

```
<a href="http://www.first_site.com" onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','500','300','yes'); window.location='http://www.second_site.com'; return false">Anything</a>
```

Note that if you don't make it return false, it opens the same site the popup window opens.

**EDIT:** Sorry for confusing the site order. Here's the correct version:

```
<a href="http://www.second_site.com" onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','500','300','yes'); window.location='http://www.first_site.com'; return false">Anything</a>
```

Comment: +'d by the efficient solution! But the OP was requesting one functionality a little different... _"when i click on Something at 1st hyper link , it open up the pop up of www.second_site.com and moves to www.first_site.com"_! **The popup of the second site is www.second_site.com!**

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same window name, both calls to `window.open` will open the url in the same window/tab. The variable `popupWindow` won't help much in your case, because the access to most of the referenced window's properties will be denied due to the same-origin-policy.

Comment: Thanks, i've started thinking to use exit popup as well as once clicked on 'Something' should leave the page then i think exit pop might helps.